# How to resolve multiple projectIDs in Firebase realtime database emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

I am using firebase emulator database and got the following warning when trying to order messages by "editedAt".

```
2023-03-24T18:21:33.576Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. 
Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "editedAt" 
at /messages to your security rules for better performance.
```

I understand to solve this warning, I need to index using editedAt

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      ".indexOn": ["editedAt"]
    }
  }
}
```

however when I try to use in my database.rules.json file, it does not resolve the warning. After looking into it further I found that

1 - the emulator is updating rules for the wrong project ID, it should be learn-firestore-dev but it is updating learn-firestore-dev-default-rtdb

```
database: Change detected, updating rules for learn-firestore-dev-default-rtdb
```

2 - in database-debug.log I see the following warning

```
16:36:28.771 [FirebaseWorkerPool-1-3] WARN com.firebase.core.persistence.backend.dummy.EmulatorMetadataPersistence 
- Multiple projectIds are not recommended in single project mode. Requested 
namespace learn-firestore-prod, but the emulator is configured for learn-firestore-prod-default-rtdb. To 
opt-out of single project mode add/set the single_project_mode: false property in 
the firebase.json emulators config.
```

3 - [image: Firebase database emulator]

I don't know what I did to get learn-firestore-dev-default-rtdb on the emulator.

below is my firebase configuration:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },  
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

The database URL that I am using is the following

```
"http://localhost:9000/?ns=learn-firestore-dev"
```

Comment: Are you making requests via a particular SDK or directly via the REST API? Can we see a bit of application code that calls the database?

Comment: I am using the web sdk, here is an example for you `users = () => ref(this.db, 'users');`. However, if you checkout my answer, it works when I switch to the project-id that the emulator created, my question is that there are multiple project IDs in the emulator and updating the database.rules.json was affecting the one created by the emulator.

Comment: I am facing same issue, was it solved in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, doesn't resolve the problem, however is a temporary fix.  I just changed the database url to the one firebase emulator created, i.e.

```
"http://localhost:9000/?ns=learn-firestore-dev-default-rtdb"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by:

1. changing the filename of the emulator data import:

`database_export/my-db.json` to
`database_export/my-db-default-rtdb.json`.

2. update config (firebase websdk)

```js
initializeApp({
   databaseURL: http://localhost:9000/?ns=dcfk-song-signups-default-rtdb
})
```

---

Commentary:

I ran across this warning while trying to determine why api calls were returning 403.

I was importing data to the emulator by:

```bash
firebase emulators:start --debug --import=data/backup
```

It turns out, the imported data targets the project based on the filename. Also,the firebase emulator itself queries your firebase project hosted on the firebase servers via the cli. This queries the server to determine an identifier of the project in the emulator. In this case, `my-db-default-rtdb`:

```
[debug] [2024-02-03T05:29:32.812Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET 
https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project 
{"projectId":"my-project", ... 
"resources":{..."realtimeDatabaseInstance":"my-db-default-rtdb"}
...
```

(You can access these logs by running the emulator with --debug)

Even though I had not explicitly declared `my-db-default-rtdb` anywhere locally, the emulator had retrieved this from the server.

I believe this may be relevant to the steps I took to set up persistence for the emulators locally. At this point, there was only one project visible locally. I had originally exported json from my prd db, imported it to the emulator via the gui, and then exported by running `firebase emulators:export ./data/backup`. This saved to `database_export/my-db.json`. I'm not sure at what step `my-db-default-rtdb` started appearing.

Hopefully if someone else runs into the problem, even this incomplete level of documentation may save them some time.

Doing all of this did not remove the warning, but my emulator was loading data into the wrong project.